# I have 2 radio buttons and i want to make a different ajax page load into a div element depending on which one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Radio Buttons that are used to select between 2 locations so that a different PHP page can be loaded from an external file when selected. But the file does also need to have an automatic refresh so that it can show the most up to date information every 3 minutes.

These are my radio buttons:

```
<div class="locationdrop">
    <div class="dropbtn">Location</div>
        <div class="locationlist">
            <input type="radio" id="location1" name="location" value="Location 1" class="locationinput" checked="checked">
            <label for="location1" class="locationlabel">Location 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="location2" name="location" value="Location 2" class="locationinput">
            <label for="location2" class="locationlabel">Location 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Script (using an auto updating AJAX):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function getData() {
            if(document.getElementById('location1').checked) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'location1data.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                    } 
                });
            }else if(document.getElementById('location2').checked) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'location2data.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                    } 
                });
                getData();
                setInterval(function () {
                    getData(); 
                }, 120000);  // it will refresh your data every 3 mins
            };
        };
    });
</script>
```

This is my original (working) code to load the php into the div:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'locationData.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        getData();
        setInterval(function () {
            getData(); 
        }, 120000);  // it will refresh your data every 1 sec
     });
</script>
```

I just need it to choose between 2 of these using the radio buttons.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Move the `setInterval()` out of the `else` block and move `getData()` out of the `getData` function body

Comment: @phil the div is still empty and I'm not sure what you mean about the getData() part, that was already working, but thanks for spotting that it was in else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getData() {
        if(document.getElementById('location1').checked) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'location1data.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                } 
            });
        }else if(document.getElementById('location2').checked) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'location2data.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#locationoutput').html(data);
                } 
            });
        };
    };

    getData();
    setInterval(function () {
        getData(); 
    }, 120000);  // it will refresh your data every 3 mins
});
```

This is more efficient

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let location_one = document.getElementById('location1');
    let location_two = document.getElementById('location2');

    let getLocationOneData = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'location1data.php',
            success: function(data){
                $('#locationoutput').html(data);
            }
        });
    };

    let getLocationTwoData = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'location2data.php',
            success: function(data){
                $('#locationoutput').html(data);
            }
        });
    };

    let getData = function () {
        if (location_one.checked) {
            getLocationOneData();
        } else if (location_two.checked) {
            getLocationTwoData();
        }
    }

    location_one.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            getLocationOneData()
        }
    });

    location_two.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            getLocationTwoData();
        }
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        getData();
    }, 120000);  // it will refresh your data every 3 mins
});
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to make the output to update as soon as you select the radio button?

Comment: You need to add a listener to your element. I will update my answer

Comment: Does that still auto refresh every 3 minutes?

Comment: No it does not. Why would you need that anyway? It now triggers the function whenever the checkbox 'change' event is fired, by checking it for example

Comment: I need that because The system that uses it needs to have a constant update without any user interaction

Comment: I understand. I will update it once more :)

Comment: Its a set it and forget it situation for new data to show up, the user just needs to interact with the data that is there XD

Comment: Didn't test the code tho, you might wanna do that but this is what I came up with.

Comment: Ok, I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Goodluck with it!

Comment: So it does work, but you do have to select the radio button for it to load anything, it doesn't use the one that is already checked when the page loads....  mm

Comment: Above `setInterval` you can call `getData();` to initialize it. Like you did before

Comment: Thank You Sooo Much :D
Now i just have to do this a few more times for the rest of my location-based data divs XD

Comment: No problem! Goodluck, you would help me if you upvote the answer :)

Comment: I totally would, I need reputation 15 to do it though :|

Comment: On my iPad 2 (that did show the data using my JS before the radio button addition) the data now doesn't show up. I have tried looking around for a way to use a conditional HTML tag to use the "Try this:" JS instead of the "This is more efficient" version. Is there anything you can suggest to allow it to work on the iPad 2?

Answer (score 0):

simply set URL value in variable,
var myURL = "location2data.php";
use it such

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: myURL,  //// here 
            success: function(data){
                $('#locationoutput').html(data);
            }
```